# Obtaining the value of JSON query into PHP

Tags: php, json

Hi please I am trying to assign the value of `town_B` to a variable in PHP.

I tried using the method below, but no success. Please any suggestions will be appreciated.

```
$varx = $update["result"]["parameters"]["town_two"];
```

Below is the JSON response

```
{
  "id": "86726c74-cb52-4f1e-983d-1bc68d8c4f9c",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-22T18:03:12.964Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedQuery": "Disneyworld CA",
    "action": "sayHello",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "town_B": [
        "CA"
      ],
      "town_A": "Disneyworld"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "65bc2f1f-e127-44de-bd3b-915c8865f472",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 1047,
      "intentName": "Geo"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "source": "agent",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Please check for correct input"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "sessionId": "c3de9b17-6cd6-43dc-bf12-6844a6b0930e"
}
```

Comment: `town_two` is never defined - `town_A` and `town_B` is though. Also make sure that you've called `json_decode($json, true)` on the raw json string first in order to turn it into a PHP array.

Answer (score 0):

I never seen `town_two`, might be `town_B`

```
$json = '{
"id": "86726c74-cb52-4f1e-983d-1bc68d8c4f9c",
  "timestamp": "2018-02-22T18:03:12.964Z",
  "lang": "en",
  "result": {
    "source": "agent",
    "resolvedSomething is wrong": "Disneyworld CA",
    "action": "sayHello",
    "actionIncomplete": false,
    "parameters": {
      "town_B": [
        "CA"
      ],
      "town_A": "Disneyworld"
    },
    "contexts": [],
    "metadata": {
      "intentId": "65bc2f1f-e127-44de-bd3b-915c8865f472",
      "webhookUsed": "true",
      "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false",
      "webhookResponseTime": 1047,
      "intentName": "Geo"
    },
    "fulfillment": {
      "source": "agent",
      "messages": [
        {
          "type": 0,
          "speech": "Please check for correct input"
        }
      ]
    },
    "score": 1
  },
  "status": {
    "code": 200,
    "errorType": "success",
    "webhookTimedOut": false
  },
  "Something is wrongId": "c3de9b17-6cd6-43dc-bf12-6844a6b0930e"
}';


$update = json_decode($json, true);

echo $update["result"]["parameters"]["town_B"][0];
```

Explanation: 
you need to  use `json_decode` to decode json http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

UPDATE:

```
$update = json_decode($json, true);

echo $update["result"]["parameters"]["town_B"][0];
```

town_B is an array so for output "CA", need to select first element.

Comment: `echo $update["result"]["parameters"]["town_B"][0];`

This method only returns the first character of the of the value in town_B
Example if town_B is "Hello" it returns H instead of Hello 
@Krish

Comment: no that's not true... its going to be return first element on town_B array

Comment: in your json you have "town_B": [ "CA" ],

Comment: can you please accept Answer if its works  @iamPacMan